# Waiting for asynchronous I/O on Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, retrofit

I have been trying for awhile to figure out an issue with Asynchronous i/o in an android application that I am working on.

This application is required to download data to from a series of tables from Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Once the data has been down it must preform a series of operations on the data to fill out some forms.

My problem is that I must wait for the downloads to be complete in order to start the update process.

If I add a any form of wait to my code it seems that it blocks indefinitely and never executes the callback.

I have tried methods using AtomicBooleans, AtomicIntegers, and CountDownLatchs with no success.

Here is an example using an AtomicInteger.

final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

```
OrganizationServiceProxy orgService;
orgService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(Constant.ENDPOINT, CRMLogin.getRequestInterceptor());

ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet();

columnSet.AddColumns(AccountEntry.FETCH_COLS);

orgService.Retrieve(AccountEntry.ENTITY, UUID.fromString(accountid), columnSet, new Callback<Entity>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Entity entity, Response response) {

        Account account = new Account();
        //Load the existing fields for the account

        account.load(index);
        String activityid = account.getValue(AccountEntry.ACTIVITY_ID);
        String recordid = account.getValue(AccountEntry.RECORD_ID);
        String name = account.getValue(AccountEntry.ACCOUNT_NAME);
        //Overload the fields for the account

        account.load(entity);
        //Reset overloaded fields on the account.
        account.setValue(AccountEntry.ACTIVITY_ID, activityid);
        account.setValue(AccountEntry.RECORD_ID, recordid);
        account.setValue(AccountEntry.ACCOUNT_NAME, name);
        //overwrite the record in the database.

        account.setValue(AccountEntry.SYNCED, "1");
        account.update();
        Log.d("pullAccount>>>", accountid + " " + "pulled.");

        latch.countDown();

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Log.d("pullAccount>>>", accountid + " " + error.getMessage());

        latch.countDown();

    }
});

try{
    latch.await(); //THIS BLOCKS FOREVER AND EVER
}
catch (Exception e){

}
```

Of note is the CallBack is implemented using Retrofit.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `AsyncTask` it will handle what you want in a way that Android is optimized for.  There is example usage here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

EDIT:

I kinda threw this together, let me know if it works as you would expect

```
public class AsyncOrganizationService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Entity> {
@Override
protected Entity doInBackground(Void... params) {
    final CountDownLatch blocker = new CountDownLatch(1);
    OrganizationServiceProxy orgService;
    orgService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(Constant.ENDPOINT, CRMLogin.getRequestInterceptor());
    ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet();
    columnSet.AddColumns(AccountEntry.FETCH_COLS);
    final SettableFuture<Entity> result = SettableFuture.create();
    orgService.Retrieve(AccountEntry.ENTITY, UUID.fromString(accountid), columnSet, new SortedList.Callback<Entity>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Entity entity, HttpHelper.Response response) {
            result.set(entity);
            blocker.countDown();
        }
    });
    try {
        blocker.await();
        return result.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Entity entity) {
    Account account = new Account();
    //Load the existing fields for the account

    account.load(index);
    String activityid = account.getValue(AccountEntry.ACTIVITY_ID);
    String recordid = account.getValue(AccountEntry.RECORD_ID);
    String name = account.getValue(AccountEntry.ACCOUNT_NAME);
    //Overload the fields for the account

    account.load(entity);
    //Reset overloaded fields on the account.
    account.setValue(AccountEntry.ACTIVITY_ID, activityid);
    account.setValue(AccountEntry.RECORD_ID, recordid);
    account.setValue(AccountEntry.ACCOUNT_NAME, name);
    //overwrite the record in the database.

    account.setValue(AccountEntry.SYNCED, "1");
    account.update();
    Log.d("pullAccount>>>", accountid + " " + "pulled.");
}
```

Im using Guava's `SettableFuture` class (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html).  Guava is quite an amazing library  - if you're not using it you should consider doing so.  Otherwise, you could whip something up really quick

Comment: I am not sure that this technique would work using callbacks as denoted above.

Could you provide code to demonstrate what you are thinking for the above request response scenario?

Comment: I'll give it a try and see how it works and post my results, thanks for the code.

Comment: So I ran this and it still suffers from the problem that when ever i wait for the service I wait forever. It is a nice service however and I edited my code to reflect the service.

Comment: To be clear I don't need to wait on an individual task to complete I need to wait on a group of AsynTasks to complete.